# Is it possible to distribute Image Units with my application?

Tags: macos, cocoa, quartz-graphics

**Mac OS X Mavericks**

I was told that the issue was fixed in Mac OS X 10.9

**Original**

I read the documentation and didn't find the answer. It suggests to create Image Units, it requires to put this unit inside either `~/Library/Graphics/Image Units` or /`Library/Graphics/Image Units` (putting the image unit inside `Your.app/Contents/Library/Graphics/Image Units` has no effect).

There is other, non-recommeneded way, to create Image Unit, which allows you to distribute cikernels and access the filter from your code. But it prevent you from creating non executable filters which is a big lack of performance.

I looked through the contents of bundles of applications like Pixelmator or Acorn and found that they don't use Image Units as well. I hope this is a mistake and there is a way to distribute Image Units within an application bundle.

I'm looking for a solution that will be accepted by Mac App Store validation.

**Solution which doesn't allow you to use non executable filters**

From the CIPlugIn header:
/** Loads a plug-in specified by its URL. */

```
+ (void)loadPlugIn:(NSURL *)url allowNonExecutable:(BOOL)allowNonExecutable
AVAILABLE_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_0_AND_LATER_BUT_DEPRECATED_IN_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7;

/** Loads a plug-in specified by its URL.

 If allowExecutableCode is NO, filters containing executable code will not be loaded. If YES, any kind of filter will be loaded. */
+ (void)loadPlugIn:(NSURL *)url allowExecutableCode:(BOOL)allowExecutableCode
AVAILABLE_MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_7_AND_LATER;
```

New method isn't listed in official docs. So, to load bundle you simply do:

```
if (floor(NSAppKitVersionNumber) <= NSAppKitVersionNumber10_6)
{
    [CIPlugIn loadPlugIn:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"YourPlugin" withExtension:@"plugin"]
      allowNonExecutable:YES];
}
else
{
    [CIPlugIn loadPlugIn:[[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"YourPlugin" withExtension:@"plugin"]
     allowExecutableCode:YES];
}
```

Unfortunately if you try to use CIFilter with QuartzCore framework (e.g. with CALayer) app will crash because of stack overflow.

```
frame #0: 0x00007fff8b6a5d36 CoreImage`-[CIFilter copyWithZone:] + 12
frame #1: 0x00007fff8b7d1c7e CoreImage`-[CIPlugInStandardFilter _provideFilterCopyWithZone:] + 18
frame #2: 0x00007fff8b6a5d59 CoreImage`-[CIFilter copyWithZone:] + 47
frame #3: 0x00007fff8b7d1c7e CoreImage`-[CIPlugInStandardFilter _provideFilterCopyWithZone:] + 18
frame #4: 0x00007fff8b6a5d59 CoreImage`-[CIFilter copyWithZone:] + 47
frame #5: 0x00007fff8b7d1c7e CoreImage`-[CIPlugInStandardFilter _provideFilterCopyWithZone:] + 18
frame #6: 0x00007fff8b6a5d59 CoreImage`-[CIFilter copyWithZone:] + 47
```

Comment: Are you calling `[CIPlugin loadAllPlugIns]` at application startup?

Answer (score 2):

As well as the Library paths you mention, Mac OS X will also look in `YourApp.app/Contents/Library`.

I think everything should work if you put your Image Unit in `YourApp.app/Contents/Library/Graphics/Image Units/`.

Comment: I'm sorry, misspelled path inside app's bundle. That doesn't work, I already tried.

Comment: That's annoying, and I definitely think you should report it to Apple as a bug. Would it be possible for your app to provide a link to your site so that users can download and install the bundle manually? I realise that this is far from ideal.

Comment: Yeah, I'll file a bug then. I assumed there is a sort of plist option that I should set to tell the system where to look for Image Units.